# How to trim and pass the `html` text to variable with easiest way?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working with an app using `angularjs`. i am getting `html` codes from other developer. i require that all need to stored in a object.

each time i am reworking to store in the variable like this:

```
var update = function () {
 string1 +="<div>some infor1 </div>"
 string1 +="<div>some infor2 </div>"
 string1 +="<div>some infor3 </div>"
 string1 +="<div>some infor4 </div>"
 string1 +="<div>some infor5 </div>"
 string1 +="<div>some infor6 </div>"

return string1;
}
```

but I am looking for a way to just copy and paste the html to an variable. I know that there is any issue with white-space and all.. but how come up with that?

here is my sample html:

```
<div class="projectInfo">
    <div class="column design">
        <span>Design Phase</span>
    </div>
    <div class="column projects">    
        <div class="flip-container">
            <div class="flipper">
                <div class="front">
                    <h3>
                        <span class="num">10</span>
                        <span class="numCount">Projects</span>
                    </h3>
                </div>
                <div class="back">
                    <h3>
                        <span class="num">10</span>
                        <span class="numCount">Projects</span>
                    </h3>
                </div>
            </div>
       </div>                   
   </div>
   <div class="column percent">
       <span>45%</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

[Here you can update](http://jsfiddle.net/dxxhw7gm/)

Comment: The best thing here is **not** to store HTML templates in JavaScript code. Store them in HTML files, and then refer to them from your JavaScript code instead. Then you can use an HTML editor on them, you don't mess up your quotes, fiddle with whitespace issues, etc., etc.

Comment: To add to what @T.J.Crowder says, you could use a templating library, such as [MustacheJS](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/)

Comment: Yes, I agree. But in case of html template or keeping as a template required proper basement. I am out of that now. I am in mid of work which i continue from some one.. this is not possible now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do strongly recommend keeping your HTML in HTML files, not JavaScript files. But if you're stuck with having them in your JavaScript:

In ES6, you'll be able to use template strings.

Meanwhile, you can do this:

1. Start with `var str = '`
2. Paste the text after that `'`
3. Using any decent text editor, select the pasted text and do a series of search-and-replace operations:

   - Replace all `\` with `\\`, then
   - Replace all `'` with `\'`, then
   - Add a `\` to the end of each line in the HTML (a good text editor will let you do that with search-and-replace rather than manually)
4. Add `';` to the end

For instance:

```js
var str = '<div class="projectInfo">\
                    <div class="column design">\
                        <span>Design Phase</span>\
                    </div>\
                    <div class="column projects">\
    \
                    <div class="flip-container">\
                        <div class="flipper">\
                            <div class="front">\
                                <h3>\
                                    <span class="num">10</span>\
                                    <span class="numCount">Projects</span>\
                                </h3>\
                            </div>\
                            <div class="back">\
                                <h3>\
                                    <span class="num">10</span>\
                                    <span class="numCount">Projects</span>\
                                </h3>\
                            </div>\
                        </div>\
                    </div>\
    \
                    </div>\
                    <div class="column percent">\
                        <span>45%</span>\
                    </div>\
                </div>';
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", str);
```

Answer (score 0):

I do strongly agree keeping your HTML in HTML files (would suggest you to change whatever current implementation is)

if not then you could use below steps to create html sting
you could use some editor like Notepad++

and follow steps:

- remove any blank lines
- replace all `\r` with `' +`
- add `'` at    start of each line (you can do this by pressing Alt and  select start of each row and type)
- add `;` to the end

now your html is ready as a single string you can copy paste it to a variable and use it.